# taxonomy_term entity loadByProperties depth not found

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

The terms returned contain depth as a Term object attribute.

```php
$vocabulary = 'category';
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$entity_storage = $entity_manager->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
$terms = $entity_storage->loadTree($vocabulary);
```

However, when I try to load terms by depth, I get an error.

```php
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$entity_storage = $entity_manager->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
$terms = $entity_storage->loadByProperties([
  'vid' => $vocabulary,
  'depth' => 0,
]);
```

The error is the following.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: "'depth' not found

What is the way to find attributes I can use on `loadByProperties()`?

Comment: Because there is no such thing as "depth". I think you're looking for `parent`

Comment: It is, but only as object attribute when loading terms via loadTree, not as field values in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the way to find attributes I can use on loadByProperties()?

I guess with [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s Kint, loading one and then looking at the "iterator contents" tab

```
  $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $entity_storage = $entity_manager->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  $term = $entity_storage->load(1);
  kint($term);
```

[image]