# How to use loadByProperties when one of the properties is an array?

Tags: 8, entities

I have this configuration entity and I want to load an entity using the properties label and subregions

[image]

Lets say I want to load the entity if it has the label CU and the subregions CU-04. Note that subregions is an array. I tried with this code but is not working.

```
$region = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('region')->loadByProperties(['label' => $region, 'subregions' => $subregion]);
```

How can I call loadbyProperties with properties being arrays?

Comment: First time I see the "Properties" tab, did the "[Iterator Contents](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296097/taxonomy-term-entity-loadbyproperties-depth-not-found/296105#296105)" tab get renamed?

Comment: Just for clarity, `$subregion = ['CU-04' => 'CU-04'];` correct?

Comment: @NoSssweat, this is a config entity, they don't have iterators. They are a simple representation of an array with an arbitrary amount of levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration entities are not queried via SQL, you search within a multilevel array.

See the code docs:

*core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/Query/Query.php*

```
  /**
   * Overrides \Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryBase::condition().
   *
   * Additional to the syntax defined in the QueryInterface you can use
   * placeholders (*) to match all keys of an subarray. Let's take the follow
   * yaml file as example:
   * @code
   *  level1:
   *    level2a:
   *      level3: 1
   *    level2b:
   *      level3: 2
   * @endcode
   * Then you can filter out via $query->condition('level1.*.level3', 1).
   */
  public function condition($property, $value = NULL, $operator = NULL, $langcode = NULL) {
    return parent::condition($property, $value, $operator, $langcode);
  }
```

In your case the second level keys are the same as the values. So you have to ignore the second level with an * to query these values.